# Cobertura "unable to locate file" problem

Tags: cobertura

Can anyone please help me to understand what is wrong here?

I am using Cobertura 1.9.4.1 for Java Code Coverage. 
I want to attache the source file with HTML report, I am generating report using the below command:

```
cobertura-report.sh --format html --datafile  $COBERTURA_HOME/core/emscore.ser --basedir $COBERTURA_HOME/core/src --destination $REPORT_DIR
```

HTML report generated successfully. Where I click on the file name in HTML report, it is giving the below error:

> "Unable to locate com/airvana/serverImpl/ObjectDao.java. Have you specified the source directory?"

However I have the Java source file at:

```
$COBERTURA_HOME/core/src/com/airvana/serverImpl/ObjectDao.java
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer from Cobertura's Developer forum. You can also submit your problem to cobertura-devel@lists.sourceforge.net

The final command I used to attache the source with HTML report is the below ().

cobertura-report.sh --format html --datafile $COBERTURA_HOME/core/emscore.ser --destination $REPORT_DIR $COBERTURA_HOME/core/src

Answer (score 3):

using "--srcdir" instead of "--basedir" worked for me

Comment: This is awesome advise as the [Cobertura command line documentation](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/Command-Line-Reference) doesn't tell us about this and nothing else seems to work. Thank-you for sharing this!

Comment: Any idea how to do this with `mvn` from the command line (as opposed to editing the `pom.xml`)?