# Cobertura “unable to locate file” in Ant build.xml

Tags: java, ant, cobertura, spring-tool-suite

This question is an **extension** of the question here, which asks how to locate a source file for Cobertura HTML reports using command-line arguments: [Cobertura "unable to locate file" problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592448/cobertura-unable-to-locate-file-problem?answertab=active#tab-top)

The answer given was to use the following command:

```
cobertura-report.sh --format html --datafile $COBERTURA_HOME/core/emscore.ser 
--destination $REPORT_DIR $COBERTURA_HOME/core/src
```

I am using an Ant build.xml file in Spring Tool Suite, rather than command line.

**Can anyone help me translate the answer above into Ant commands?**

This is my script so far:

```
<property name="src" location="${basedir}/src" />
<cobertura-report format="html" destdir="${cob.reports}">
   <fileset dir="${src}">
       <include name="**/*.java" />
   </fileset>
</cobertura-report>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Cobertura reference page](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/Ant-Task-Reference) shows that the Cobertura-Report Task provides attributes including `format`, `datafile`, `destdir` and `srcdir`. So you should be able to reproduce that commandline using those, e.g.

```
<cobertura-report format="html" datafile="<path_to>/emscore.ser" destdir="${cob.reports}">
   <fileset dir="${src}">
       <include name="**/*.java" />
   </fileset>
</cobertura-report>
```